# How to account for delay in response from api server on http requests in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, web-applications

I am making an HTTP post request to an API server. I have a function that makes the call, then returns true or false based on the value of the response. However, when I try to evaluate the response it is undefined, thus making my function always return false.

I thought about making a while(response == undefined) loop simply to wait until the value is defined before evaluating it, but is there another solution?

```
apiCall(): any{
 let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 var result; 
 this.http.post(this.url, this.data, {headers: headers}).subscribe(
  res => {
    result = res; 
  }
 );

 return result; 
}

evaluate() : boolean {
 var response = apiCall();
 if(response == 1968){
    return true; 
 }
 else return false; 
}
```

I want to return the true or false from my evaluate function based on the value of the api response.

Comment: Just return the call don't subscribe it in apiCall subscribe it in component or from where you actually call it and then subscribe there and wait fir result. Then you can do apiCall().subscribe(res => ..... Your code . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple but very confusing mechanic to newcomers of Javascript, which is a single-threaded asynchronous language by design, it makes many aspects a lot easier...

It's not possible to delay code executing explicitly such as in other languages. What your code is doing, is creating a result variable, executing the request, subscribing to the request, and then immediately returning the `result` variable, which is still `undefined`.

When you subscribe, you pass in a [callback function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) using the shorthand arrow syntax. `data => { ... }` is basically the same as `function(data) { ... }`.

When the response is received, the callback function is executed, which updates the variable. However, this is meaningless. The `result` variable is only available within the scope of the `apiCall` function, which has already returned, you update a variable that is never used again.

```
var response = apiCall();
```

apiCall will immediately return with an empty `result` variable. The request is being processed in the background. `while` loops won't work, they will block the thread, meaning it can't handle the response and create useless work. The solution is much simpler, abide by the rules of asynchronous logic.

I'll let you do some research on async Javascript (callbacks, promises, async/await), but angular makes it easy to do with the `subscribe` pattern. Underneath, it uses `Rxjs` and observables.

The easiest approach would be to follow the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http). Your api call should return the Observable from `http.post`, and any consumers of this data should subscribe to it, passing in a function to execute at a later time.

Just remember, any callbacks most likely don't execute at the same time as the rest of your code. Think of it as a chain, each one leading to the next event. That's how it should work, and there shouldn't be any crisscrossing.

```
function apiCall() {
...
return this.http.post("https://...", data, headers);
}

function getData() {
apiCall()
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data.response === 200) {
      ...do something now that the response is known
    }
  });
}
```

Bear in mind, you can't return true/false from `getData` for the same reasons, it has already returned. You must continue to chain actions, or if you really want to try that approach, see `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix the issue by using `setTimeout()` on the request in question.